# SPD 2013 Workflow, choice field picking default value

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have created simple list workflow using SPD 2013 on document library, added ReviewerEMails column(set as choice column) and added 4-5 emails.

Now when I am trying to log selected value(ReviewerEMails columns) to the  workflow history list, it always takes the Default value which I have set when creating column.

Any suggestions where I am doing wrong?

**Edits**

Workflow is picking selected value of 'ReviewerEMails' column only first time correctly after on adding any more documents it takes default value i.e 'xyz@test.com'

Adding Screen shots

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your workflow after removing/blurring sensitive information.

Comment: see my edits, I added screenshots

Comment: What you want? No default value? or selected value to be picked in workflow? or you want to select any value from choices in workflow?

Comment: I want the selected value to be picked in workflow, whenever workflow starts

Answer (score 0):

- Keep default value empty in column setting as below.

[image]

Once done, create a new item/upload document and select any value, and see workflow will pick the correct value.

Comment: I tried this, removed all instances of WFs, empty default choice value. Now first time it runs correctly and then it says 'Value is empty or null' as I set message on empty.